# print RGB values of image using wand in python

Tags: python, image-processing, wand

i have resized an image into "1x1" in order to get the average color using wand library in python but now i want to print the "RGB" values of that resized "1x1" image. i am new to wand so any guidance or help would be really appreciated.this is the code i have written so far.

```
with Image(filename='E:/Miro/images/test.jpg') as image:
with image.clone() as img:
    img.resize(1,1)
```

i just want to know if there is a function in wand library to access "RGB" values of image.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `resize 1x1` is a good method to get the average color of the image. I don't know what `wand` is. But if you have read the image into `numpy.ndarray`, then you can get the avg like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.10.02 19:07:21 CST

import cv2

def getAvg(img):
    nh,nw = img.shape[:2]
    nc = 1 if img.ndim==2 else img.shape[2]
    avg = img.reshape(-1, nc).sum(axis=0)/(nw*nh)
    return avg

img = cv2.imread("doll.jpg")
avg = getAvg(img)
print("Avg: {}".format(avg))

# Avg: [148.661125 146.273425 155.205675]
```

Comment: thanks much, that's really helpful but i think wand's "resize 1x1" is faster and it can be done by calling just one function, that's why i want to use it @Silencer